# In Ruby, is there a way to use something like hash.each_with_index do |[k,v], i|?

Tags: ruby

Otherwise, it needs to be

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2.2}
h.each_with_index do |pair, i|
  k = pair[0]; v = pair[1]
  p k, v, i
end
```

and setting the `k` and `v` this way seems a bit clumsy.  Can it be simpler or something like

```
h.each_with_index do |[k,v], i|
```

?

Comment: Just a note: you can do `k, v = *pair` anywhere you need to do something like what you have in `k = pair[0]; v = pair[1]`.

Comment: Even `k, v = pair` works. No `*` needed here.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

In fact, yes! Use parentheses:

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2.2}
h.each_with_index do |(k, v), i|
  p k, v, i
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Inject call should get what you want, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.src/M001494.html check that and scroll to the Inject portion, should work like a charm!

Comment: myArray.inject { |kvPair, seed| //do stuff! }